# Catch exception thrown by custom session handler

Tags: php, session

I have a custom session handler which throws an `\Exception` on certain conditions.

Simplified example:

```
class MyHandler implements \SessionHandlerInterface
{
    // ... code snipped

    public function write($sid, $value)
    {
        // ... code snipped    
        throw new \Exception('some error');     
    }   
}
```

Running the code below, PHP logs the error as uncaught exception but I can't seem to catch it with a try/catch block e.g.,

```
try {
    $_SESSION['test'] = 'foo';
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting. As per remarks scattered across documentation ([Please note the callback methods of this class are designed to be called internally by PHP and are not meant to be called from user-space code](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php), [The return value (usually TRUE on success, FALSE on failure). Note this value is returned internally to PHP for processing.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sessionhandlerinterface.write.php#refsect1-sessionhandlerinterface.write-returnvalues)) I suspect the API is just not designed to allow that.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález looks like it. I guess an alternative is to `trigger_error()` instead and deal with it in another way.